# Ngx Bootstrap Elements Not Showing

Tags: angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4, frontend, ngx-bootstrap

I have add Ngx Bootstrap to my angular project. After that I have create module called `UI Elements`.

`ui-elements.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class UiElementsModule { }
```

After that I have import above module into main `app module`

`app.module.ts`

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LayoutsModule } from './layouts/layouts.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutsModule,
    UiElementsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`customer.component.html`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
    Simple demo
</button>
```

But still Ngx Bootstrap is not working. There is no Error.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an bootstrap CSS?

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We">
```

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started

Comment: No. because I have use Angular CLI to add ngx-bootstrap